# <div> elements disappearing when display:inline or float:left is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script to display three `<div>` elements that works correctly but when I add either `display: inline` or `float: left` the three blocks disappear.

This is my first JavaScript project and just kind of a sandbox for me.

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Paint by Pixels</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pixel_styles.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas"></div>
    <script src="pixel_script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
.pixel {
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 2px;
}

.canvas {
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var $newPixel = $('<div class="pixel"></div>');
    $('div.canvas').prepend($newPixel);
}
```

I can't upload images yet, but the result is three vertical black boxes and when the CSS I mentioned at the top is added they disappear instead of becoming inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are there - but they have no width. If you use `inline-block` and set a `min-width` they display fine (you can remove `min-width` if you have content in these divs).

```
.pixel {
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```